# Is vinegar dangerous for dishwashers?

Tags: chemistry, household, causality

[This post](http://wholenewmom.com/whole-new-budget/natural-dishwasher-rinse-aid-important-update/) claims that putting vinegar in rinse aid reservoir of a dishwasher leads to damage (similar claims can be found [here](http://ofthehearth.com/is-rinse-aid-in-your-dishwasher-really-beneficial/) and [here](http://dishwashers.reviewed.com/features/what-the-heck-is-rinse-aid-and-why-do-i-need-it)):

> on newer dishwashers, the rinse aid compartments have rubber components that aren’t really compatible with acidic things like vinegar.

On the other hand, [this dishwasher manual](https://www.miele.com.au/pmedia/ZGA/TX2070/9585880-000-01_9585880-01.pdf) from 2005 explicitly allows the use on vinegar:

> Alternatively, it is possible to use household vinegar with a max. 5% acid content

Also, the book of [Advanced Cleaning Product Formulations, Volume 4](https://books.google.com/books?id=H6CPSH9qaIEC&pg=PA127) lists the following recipe for rinse aid:

> - Deionized water     - 30%
> - Mazawet 36          - 55%
> - **Glycolic acid (57%) - 10%**
> - Isopropil alcohol   - 5%

So, in essence:

- at least some dishwashers are not damaged by vinegar
- dishwashers compatible with common rinse aids are not damaged by weak acids

Is there any evidence of an actual dishwasher which got damaged by regular 5% household vinegar? So far I have only seen two statements, of which neither can count as evidence:

1. *My repairman told me not to use it* - it basically means that anything home-made should be used at your own risk.
2. *I started to use vinegar and my dishwasher broke down* - [Correlation is not causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation).

Comment: VTC as a random blog post is not a notable claim.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill [here](http://dishwashers.reviewed.com/features/what-the-heck-is-rinse-aid-and-why-do-i-need-it)'s another one. How many do you need to call it notable?

Comment: Your second link has only one thing to say about vinegar, and it's "we'd speculate that loading vinegar in your rinse aid dispenser is probably not a great idea". That's a long way from even being a claim.